# Prove there exists an integer coefficient polynomial $q(x)$ such that $f(x)$ equivalent to $q(x)(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_k)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Suppose $p$ is prime, $f(x)$ is a integer coefficient polynomial, and $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_k$ have distinct residuals modulo $p$, which satisfy $f(a_i)\equiv0\;(\mod p)$.
>
> Prove here exists an integer coefficient polynomial $q(x)$ such that $f(x)$ equivalent to $q(x)(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_k)$.

Note: Tow polynomials are equivalent, if their corresponding coefficients are congruent  to $p$.

If it's true for each $f(x)$ of degree no more than $k$, then by induction, we can prove it. But I don't know how to prove it when the degree of $f(x)$ no more than $k$.

Comment: Hint: divide $f(x)$ by $(x-a_1)\dotsb(x-a_k)$ with a remainder. The remainder has degree smaller than $k$ and you can apply to it what you proved by induction.